# Symfony 1.4: how to differentiate between two forms in the same module

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

- I have one module: "Job"
- Within Job, I have two partials: 
  _partialA
  _partialB

Both partials use the same JobForm.Class.php

Here's the question/what I'm trying to achieve:

in JobForm.Class.php:

```
function removeFields()
{
if ($partialName == 'partialA'){
unset ($this['field_a']);
}
if($partialName == 'partialB'){
unset ($this['field_b']);
}
}
```

Obviously, I'm having difficulty defining "$partialName'

Help?  Suggestions?  Is there another/better way of going about achieving the same desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you should define 2 forms instead

Comment: Didn't know you could do that in the same module.  How would I go about that?

Comment: you can define as many classes as you want extending your model form class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually used the solution suggested by Andreu Heineken (love the beer, by the way) above, but thanks, Dan, for your solution as well.  I just created a new Formclass and extended the baseModule I needed.

Here's a link for the details: [Solution to question](http://shlamp2012.blogspot.com/2011/12/symfony-14-2-forms-1-module.html)

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would not teach the form about your partial names, because it should not be tied to your view layer. Instead, find a semantic name for the setting you are trying to achieve (maybe 'withExtraFields' or so, I'm just guessing).

That being said, there are at least 3 ways to do what you're trying:

You can either pass it as an option to the form:

```
$form = new JobForm($job, array('withExtraFields' => true));
```

and then act on it inside the form:

```
if($this->getOption('withExtraFields') //do something
```

Or you could unset things in the controller (probably not the best place):

```
//actions.class.php
if($partialName == 'partialA') unset($form['field_a']);
```

Or, as suggested above, you can create 2 different forms (best if multiple fields or different validation rules apply):

```
//actions.class.php
if($partialName == 'partialA') $form = SpecialJobForm();
else $form = NotSoSpecialJobForm();
```

Hope this helps.
Daniel